# Cannot find module imported in Nodejs Express

Tags: node.js, express, import

Hi everyone I'm learning about NodeJS and I'm having trouble importing between files

**userController.js file**

```
import userService from "../services/userService";

const userController = {
    show: (request, response) => {
        response.send(userService.show);
    }
}

export default userController;
```

**userService.js file**

```
const userService = {
    show: () => {
        return 1;
    }
}

export default userService;
```

I'm sure my path is correct

This is the error displayed in the console

```
internal/process/esm_loader.js:74
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/path_here/services/userService' imported from /path_here/controllers/userController.js
    at finalizeResolution (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:285:11)
    at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:708:10)
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:819:11)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:89:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:242:28)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:73:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:72:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

I tried to recall my knowledge but couldn't find the problem. Please help me check. Thanks

Comment: What is the import location vs the module path? So, for example you may just need to add another ../ or however deep the route is folder structure wise to find the correct path to modules.

Answer (score -1):

see do it like that

```
const file= required("./filename");
```